# Can you move apps to SD card without rooting or computer?

Tags: app2sd

I've done everything to move my apps to my SD card. I don't have a computer and I don't want to root my device.

So how can I do it from my Verizon LG optimus Exceed 2?

Answer (score 1):

There are many apps in the appstore that will do this for you without needing to root, AppsSD for example. However some apps may not be capable of running from SD without root.

Also, if you go into the setting menu and into your Applications option, opening the details of any downloaded app should have a button that says move to SD so you can try that, but if the button is greyed then it is not SD compatible.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to move apps to SD card if the app developer has enabled or added the feature in the development phase itself.

Unless your device need to be rooted to force the apps to move into sdcard...